# Where are Mac Menu Bar icon files located (specifically, the Screen Recording/Sharing icon)?

Tags: menu-bar, accessibility

In Sonoma, there's a new Screen Recording/Sharing icon that appears in the Menu Bar. It looks like this:

[image: screen recording]

I use a handful of utilities on my Mac that use screen recording to do their thing... most notably: Bartender, Audio Hijack, DisplayLink Manager. This huge purple icon is constantly appearing and disappearing and **it's very distracting**.

I'd like to find this icon on disk so that I can maybe tone it down a bit. i.e. Make it greyscale or remove the purple background.

---

*FWIW, I have some vision issues that are exacerbated by motion in my peripheral view. This icon blinking on and off isn't helping things.*

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that you can modify system icons. The system is on a secure, read-only volume that may fail to boot if tampered with.

However, that icon indicates that your screen is being shared to another Mac. I see that when another Mac uses screen sharing to connect to my Mac's screen. For me, it is constant while the screen is shared. FWIW, I don't see that menu item when I use Audio Hijack.

If another app is continually connecting to your screen and then disconnecting, then I'd suggest that's either a bug or a security flaw, and you should report it to DisplayLink Manager's devs. *(Does Bartender really record your screen itself?)*

You can send Apple feedback about your needs, as they are usually pretty good with accessibility issues.

Comment: DisplayLink does its magic by recording the screen and outputting the stream over USB to hardware (most often a hub or dock) that converts it back to video. You might be right about the icons being protected.

Comment: Yes Bartender uses screen recording to function. Bartender 5 (the latest version compatible with macOS Sonoma) will have it persistently showing in the menu bar unfortunately. See Bartender's support page here: https://www.macbartender.com/b5blog/Bartender-is-capturing-your-screen/

Comment: Following my above comment, apparently Bartender 5 hasn't been updated to the latest APIs, so until then the screen recording icon will show in the menu bar. Once the developer updates Bartender 5 to the latest API, it will hopefully go away! See here: https://www.macbartender.com/Bartender4/support/#:~:text=You%20will%20also%20notice%20a%20new%20menu%20bar,currently%20unavoidable%2C%20because%20of%20the%20same%20API%20issue Also, some reddit pages suggest that DisplayLink Manager is the bigger issue than Bartender...